# filemaker pro 16 creating records that share a date (work rota)

Tags: filemaker

I am currently trying to create a rota within filemaker 16 and I can't figure out how to create records that share a date.

I want to be able to have people assigned to jobs and jobs assigned to dates but currently when I create jobs with the same date it creates a new record instead of assigning it to the one already existing.

I have 3 tables currently jobs, date and people. I have a 4th layout with a portal where I wanted to view records related to jobs that are set for a certain day.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Many thanks.

Comment: I have posted a brief answer, but I believe you'd be much better off posting on one of the forums dedicated  to the Filemaker platform - where you can have a back and forth conversation, incl. exchange of files if necessary.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, I have also posted the same question there hopefully will get a reply.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% convinced you need a Dates table. Do you have anything specific to record about a date, other than its existence?

However, you certainly need a *join table* of Assignments, with fields for:

- PersonID
- JobID
- Date

(this is assuming your rota is daily, otherwise you will need to indicate the shift or hours too).

Comment: I have come to realise that you are correct as date is not an entity but an attribute and that i need to have a further look at the relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I think your structure should change on this.

So instead have:
Parent:
ProjectId
Date

PersonId
JobId
Date

Then make the project Id your 'Primary Key' so your parent record.
Then you are just assigning the person, job & date as the child.

That way you can always add to the previous record without relying on date field.
You could then filter via dates etc.